# Changing AngularJS $interval delay depending on time

Tags: angularjs, setinterval

I'm trying to change the delay of an interval, depending on the time of day. Every 30 minutes, I'd like to automatically (and randomly) push up a blogpost from a predefined list, without an UI event triggering this. However, during the night, I'd like to slow down the push up (changing the delay) to not 'clog' the UI. My code:

```
var campaign_post_ids = [
  // some array
];
var today = new Date();
var hourNow = today.getHours();
var stop = $interval(function() {
}, 100);

function pushBlog(blog_id) {
  blog_id = campaign_post_ids[Math.floor(Math.random() * campaign_post_ids.length)];
  Blog.push_up(blog_id); //calling the push_up function in the Blog service
}

if (hourNow > 9 && hourNow < 23) {
  $interval.cancel(stop);
  $interval(pushBlog, 60000 * 30); //every 30 minutes
} else {
  $interval.cancel(stop);
  $interval(pushBlog, 60000 * 120); //every 120 minutes
}
```

The push up works fine, however, the change in delay does not work; during the night, it keeps pushing up every 30 minutes (instead of 120 minutes). What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

First of you're missing a part of canceling the interval. In order to cancel the interval you should declare it as a variable and use it as an argument to `$interval.cancel()`.

eg:

```
var stop = $interval(function() {
  console.log('running')
}, 100);

$interval.cancel(stop)
```

Also when hours is 9 or 23 no interval will be run at all using this code. Is this by design? You might want to remove the `else if` block and simply clear any previous interval before initializing the new one. Angular docs have nice examples of this: [$interval docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$interval)

Comment: Ah, yes, declaring the cancelling of the interval makes perfect sense... thanks for that!

Comment: Is it necessary to clear the $interval at all? I read somewhere that there will never be 2 intervals running at the same time?

Comment: You can have as many intervals as you want, in vanillja js and the angular implementation. Example: https://jsfiddle.net/57nn8xrz/

Comment: Clear! Thanks a lot for your help in this.